# Create Eclipse nested projects

Tags: eclipse

I have the following project structure in an Eclipse Neon M7 workspace:

```
CreateOperatingSystem
Documentation
ShellUtilities
```

I want to end up with the following project structure:

```
DevelopmentTools
    ShellUtilities
SupportTools
    CreateOperatingSystem
Documentation
```

where ShellUtilities and CreateOperatingSystem are nested projects as talked about in Eclipse Mars. I have been unable to find any way of creating this structure. Note that these are not Java/Maven projects. Can anyone suggest how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new project, you can set a specific location on filesystem for this project. So when creating `ShellUtilities` make sure you set its location to `/path/to/DevelopmentTools/ShellUtilities`.

Once your projects are created, they will appear in a Flat layout by default, which means that `ShellUtilities` would be at the same level as `DevelopmentTools`. To have the hierarchical layout, use the **Project Explorer** view, and get to the View Menu to select *Project Layout > Hierarchical*. Then the projects will be rendered hierarchically.

Comment: I did as you said and set a full path to the project before I posted  but it did not help.